# How do I use find_package in CMakeLists.txt such that if an optional dependency is not installed, I still get a makefile?

Tags: cmake

My goal is to create a CMakeLists.txt file that builds a suite of programs for the local system. If the conditions for building some programs are not satisfied, I wish to be able to build the rest of the programs. The sticking point seems to be gtk, but bear in mind that I don't think a gtk-specific method is the best choice.

For many modules you'd want to build with, you can use

`find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)`

To set up the pkg-config wrapper `pkg_check_Modules` and if you don't use `REQUIRED` you can check the `_FOUND` variable:

```
pkg_check_Modules(FT REQUIRED freetype2)
if (FT_FOUND)
   message(STATIC "Found freetype2")
   #Continue and succeed, using FreeType library
else()
   message(STATIC "Didn't find freetype2")
   #Continue and succeed, without using FreeType library
endif()
```

Other libraries don't seem to work with pkg_check_modules so I have resorted to `find_package`

```
find_package(GTK2 2.0 QUIET gtk)
if (GTK2_FOUND)
...
endif()
```

Here's a complete reduction:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.2)
project (test C CXX)

set (SOURCE a.cpp b.cpp)
find_package(AMAZING 2.0 QUIET amazing_testing)
if (AMAZING_FOUND)
list(APPEND SOURCE c.cpp)
else()
list(APPEND SOURCE d.cpp)
endif()

add_executable(test ${SOURCE})
```

The above allows my whole CMakeLists.txt to proceed to the end, but I get an error, no makefile is created, and build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log doesn't even mention gtk:

```
CMake Error at gtk/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  find_package called with invalid argument "amazing_testing"

## here would be further cmake processing logs from other necessary setup

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/menright/bit/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

How can I tweak such a usage of `find_package` so that if the optional package does not exist, the configure will complete successfully anyway? Alternatively, what should I use instead of `find_package` that will concisely set up usage of a library the way pkg_check_modules does and yet allow success if the library is not available?

Comment: Just `find_package(AMAZING 2.0 QUIET)`. I do not understand - `find_package` also has `REQUIRED` option and it just works exactly the same as in `pkg_check_modules`. And I also do not understand `but I get an error,` - yes, as the error says: `find_package called with invalid argument "amazing_testing"` so remove that argument.

Comment: @ZamilCuk, I think you basically have the answer. It looks like, even though I read the find_package documentation, I missed the one of the details on how to use the command. pkg_check_modules's first parameter is the root of the variable names it will fill in with the results. On the other hand, find_package is simpler, in that the first parameter is the root of the variables and the name of the package.